# How to install v8-profiler using npm on windows 7?

Tags: node.js, profiler, npm, v8, node-inspector

Tried to install v8-profiler on Windows7(64 bit)

```
npm install v8-profiler
```

Note:
1. The dependency was Python 2.7, I have installed and set the env. var. also

1. Confirmed 'Visual C++ Redistributable Package' is installed.
2. node-gyp module is also installed

But still the error thrown is as follows:

```
D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct>npm install v8-profiler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler

> v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct\node_modules\
v8-profiler
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct\node_modules\v8-profiler>node "C:\Program F
iles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\n
ode-gyp.js" rebuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform
.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'profiler.vcxproj' is i
nvalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying
to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Pl
atform that doesn't exist for this project. [D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\My_Prj
ct\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:236:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct\node_modules\v8-profiler
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.7.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the v8-profiler package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-profiler
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "v8-profiler"
npm ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.66
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

---

File: npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'v8-profiler' ]
2 info using npm@1.1.66
3 info using node@v0.8.15
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\package.json
6 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\express\package.json
7 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\hbs\package.json
8 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\mongodb\package.json
9 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\mongoose\package.json
10 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\node-inspector\package.json
11 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\package.json
12 verbose cache add [ 'v8-profiler', null ]
13 silly cache add name=undefined spec="v8-profiler" args=["v8-profiler",null]
14 verbose parsed url { pathname: 'v8-profiler',
14 verbose parsed url   path: 'v8-profiler',
14 verbose parsed url   href: 'v8-profiler' }
15 silly lockFile a12f389f-v8-profiler v8-profiler
16 verbose lock v8-profiler C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\a12f389f-v8-profiler.lock
17 silly lockFile a12f389f-v8-profiler v8-profiler
18 verbose addNamed [ 'v8-profiler', '' ]
19 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
20 silly lockFile f875d38f-v8-profiler v8-profiler@
21 verbose lock v8-profiler@ C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\f875d38f-v8-profiler.lock
22 silly addNameRange { name: 'v8-profiler', range: '', hasData: false }
23 verbose url raw v8-profiler
24 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './v8-profiler' ]
25 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler
26 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 16:54:05
27 verbose etag "ET10KXXLUBJGCCEB13YK5N04L"
28 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler
29 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/v8-profiler
30 silly registry.get cb [ 304,
30 silly registry.get   { server: 'CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B)',
30 silly registry.get     etag: '"ET10KXXLUBJGCCEB13YK5N04L"',
30 silly registry.get     date: 'Tue, 08 Jan 2013 11:21:56 GMT',
30 silly registry.get     'content-length': '0' } ]
31 verbose etag v8-profiler from cache
32 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'v8-profiler', range: '', hasData: true }
33 silly addNameRange versions [ 'v8-profiler',
33 silly addNameRange   [ '0.0.1', '0.0.2', '0.0.3', '3.6.2beta', '3.6.2beta2', '3.6.2-1' ] ]
34 verbose addNamed [ 'v8-profiler', '3.6.2-1' ]
35 verbose addNamed [ '3.6.2-1', '3.6.2-1' ]
36 silly lockFile 19e1a1b9-v8-profiler-3-6-2-1 v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
37 verbose lock v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\19e1a1b9-v8-profiler-3-6-2-1.lock
38 verbose read json C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\v8-profiler\3.6.2-1\package\package.json
39 silly lockFile 19e1a1b9-v8-profiler-3-6-2-1 v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
40 silly lockFile f875d38f-v8-profiler v8-profiler@
41 silly resolved [ { name: 'v8-profiler',
41 silly resolved     version: '3.6.2-1',
41 silly resolved     description: 'node bindings for the v8 profiler',
41 silly resolved     homepage: 'http://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler',
41 silly resolved     author: { name: 'Danny Coates', email: 'dannycoates@gmail.com' },
41 silly resolved     keywords: [ 'profiler', 'inspector' ],
41 silly resolved     engines: { node: '>=0.6' },
41 silly resolved     main: 'v8-profiler',
41 silly resolved     scripts: { install: 'node-gyp rebuild' },
41 silly resolved     gypfile: true,
41 silly resolved     readme: 'v8-profiler provides [node](http://github.com/ry/node) bindings for the v8 \nprofiler and integration with [node-inspector](http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)\n\n## Installation\n\n    npm install v8-profiler\n\n## Usage\n\n    var profiler = require(\'v8-profiler\');\n\n## API\n\n    var snapshot = profiler.takeSnapshot([name])      //takes a heap snapshot\n\n    profiler.startProfiling([name])                   //begin cpu profiling\n    var cpuProfile = profiler.stopProfiling([name])   //finish cpu profiling\n\n## node-inspector\n\nCpu profiles can be viewed and heap snapshots may be taken and viewed from the\nprofiles panel.\n',
41 silly resolved     readmeFilename: 'readme.md',
41 silly resolved     _id: 'v8-profiler@3.6.2-1',
41 silly resolved     _from: 'v8-profiler' } ]
42 info install v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 into D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3
43 info installOne v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
44 verbose from cache C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\v8-profiler\3.6.2-1\package\package.json
45 info D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler unbuild
46 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
47 verbose tar unpack C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\v8-profiler\3.6.2-1\package.tgz
48 silly lockFile cffa88b0-ce3-MY_Prjct3-node-modules-v8-profiler D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler
49 verbose lock D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cffa88b0-ce3-MY_Prjct3-node-modules-v8-profiler.lock
50 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
51 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
52 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'package.json', 438, 420 ]
53 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
54 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ '.npmignore', 438, 420 ]
55 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry v8-profiler.js
56 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'v8-profiler.js', 438, 420 ]
57 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry profile.cc
58 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'profile.cc', 438, 420 ]
59 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry graph_edge.cc
60 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'graph_edge.cc', 438, 420 ]
61 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry graph_edge.h
62 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'graph_edge.h', 438, 420 ]
63 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry graph_node.cc
64 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'graph_node.cc', 438, 420 ]
65 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry graph_node.h
66 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'graph_node.h', 438, 420 ]
67 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry heap_profiler.cc
68 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'heap_profiler.cc', 438, 420 ]
69 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry heap_profiler.h
70 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'heap_profiler.h', 438, 420 ]
71 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Makefile
72 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'Makefile', 438, 420 ]
73 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry binding.gyp
74 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'binding.gyp', 438, 420 ]
75 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry cpu_profiler.h
76 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'cpu_profiler.h', 438, 420 ]
77 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry profile.h
78 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'profile.h', 438, 420 ]
79 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry profiler.cc
80 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'profiler.cc', 438, 420 ]
81 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry profile_node.cc
82 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'profile_node.cc', 438, 420 ]
83 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry profile_node.h
84 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'profile_node.h', 438, 420 ]
85 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry readme.md
86 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'readme.md', 438, 420 ]
87 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry snapshot.cc
88 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'snapshot.cc', 438, 420 ]
89 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry snapshot.h
90 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'snapshot.h', 438, 420 ]
91 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry cpu_profiler.cc
92 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'cpu_profiler.cc', 438, 420 ]
93 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry wscript
94 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'wscript', 438, 420 ]
95 verbose read json D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
96 silly lockFile cffa88b0-ce3-MY_Prjct3-node-modules-v8-profiler D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler
97 info preinstall v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
98 verbose from cache D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
99 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
100 verbose from cache D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
101 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
102 silly resolved []
103 verbose about to build D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler
104 info build D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler
105 verbose from cache D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
106 verbose linkStuff [ false,
106 verbose linkStuff   false,
106 verbose linkStuff   false,
106 verbose linkStuff   'D:\\Projects\\Projects\\MY_Prjct3\\MY_Prjct3\\node_modules' ]
107 info linkStuff v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
108 verbose linkBins v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
109 verbose linkMans v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
110 verbose rebuildBundles v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
111 info install v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
112 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
113 silly exec cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"
114 silly cmd,/c,node-gyp rebuild,D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler spawning
115 info v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 Failed to exec install script
116 info D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler unbuild
117 verbose from cache D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules\v8-profiler\package.json
118 info preuninstall v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
119 info uninstall v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
120 verbose true,D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules,D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3\node_modules unbuild v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
121 info postuninstall v8-profiler@3.6.2-1
122 error v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
122 error `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
123 error Failed at the v8-profiler@3.6.2-1 install script.
123 error This is most likely a problem with the v8-profiler package,
123 error not with npm itself.
123 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
123 error     node-gyp rebuild
123 error You can get their info via:
123 error     npm owner ls v8-profiler
123 error There is likely additional logging output above.
124 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
125 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "v8-profiler"
126 error cwd D:\Projects\Projects\MY_Prjct3\MY_Prjct3
127 error node -v v0.8.15
128 error npm -v 1.1.66
129 error code ELIFECYCLE
130 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ compiler (from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010) is a 32-bit compiler, but you're trying to build a 64-bit program.

Install and switch to a 64-bit C++ compiler, or switch to the 32-bit version of node/npm.

Comment: I understood this issue, but I already installed Microsoft Visual C++ Express of x64 in my system. Still getting the same error... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni Well, you must also ensure that the 64-bit compiler is actually called instead of the 32 bit compiler. The easiest way to do so is uninstalling the 32-bit version of the compiler, or correcting PATH to pointing to the 64-bit one.

Comment: After changing C++ Compiler, Npm, Node.Js to 32 bit, The error has changed to :  "graph_node.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class v8::H
eapGraphNode const * __thiscall v8::HeapGraphNode::GetDominatorNode(void)const
" (?GetDominatorNode@HeapGraphNode@v8@@QBEPBV12@XZ) [C:\Users\Amol.Kulkarni\App
Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\v8-profiler\build\profiler.vcxproj]"

Answer (score 5):

V8-profiler ("version": "0.0.2") uses some V8 API's, but those API's are eliminated from V8 in version 3.11.5.
node.js upgraded v8 version from 3.9.24.31 to 3.11.10 in version 0.7.11, so all version later than 0.7.11 doesn't work.

For more Info:

https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/20

https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler/issues/16#issuecomment-9099768